# Wordpress get_user_meta showing wrong value

Tags: php, wordpress, formidable

I am attempting to do some custom snippets for my WordPress site. I have done a few already and this one for some reason isn't working. I use Formidable Forms on my site to sign users up and at the time of sign up there is a custom meta field created called "info" and the value is set to "no". This field is only changed when the user creates an entry in my customer-info form. Then the meta value is changed to "yes".

This snippet is to force them to fill out the info form when they log in and direct them to that page but for some reason the value I get from the user meta is "no". which is wrong. any ideas? Code I'm using:

```
function my_logged_in_redirect() {
    $userid = get_current_user_id();
    $info = get_user_meta($userid, 'info', true);
    $loggedin = is_user_logged_in();
    if (is_page(1795)){
        if ($loggedin == true && $info = 'no'){
            wp_redirect(home_url('/dashboard/account-information'));
        }
        else if ($loggedin == true && $info = 'yes'){
            wp_redirect(home_url('/dashboard'));
        }
        else if ($loggedin == false){
            wp_redirect(home_url());
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_logged_in_redirect' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think that right off the bat your if statement might be wrong. `if ($loggedin == true && $info = 'no'){`

should be changed to  `if ($loggedin == true && $info == 'no'){`

also this `else if ($loggedin == true && $info = 'yes'){`

to this `else if ($loggedin == true && $info == 'yes'){`

Your code doesn't look wrong aside those points ^. Looks like the `$info` might have the correct value but just the if statement was incorrect.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested above but I was getting "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" on my chrome browser.

Comment: OK, so this double equals sign works as i thought it should. After hearing you guys tell me, i went back and did some testing. What is happening is the user is succesfully being redirected to the page '/dashboard'..... BUT this script is running on the dashboard page so it keeps loading and loading over and over. i tried the die command and exit command but doesnt seem to work. how can i get this to only run once?

Comment: Are you using any sort of action hooks to run your code? Where exactly are you placing your code?

Comment: this was being placed in the code snippets plugin on my wordpress site. allows you run these codes from anywhere on the site. This one specifically is being ran when the page is being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect.
The operation of comparing two values is done in php with `==` and `===`.

- Equal to only value (==)
- Equal amount and data type (===)
- The operator (=) is used to set the value

This code is correct:

```php
if (is_page(1795)) {
    if ($loggedin == true && $info == 'no') {
        wp_redirect(home_url('/dashboard/account-information'));
    } else if ($loggedin == true && $info == 'yes') {
        wp_redirect(home_url('/dashboard'));
    } else if ($loggedin == false) {
        wp_redirect(home_url());
    }
}
```

For more information, refer to this link

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp